# For predicting new observations from a multiple regression model, can I drop any predictors used in the new observation?

Tags: r, prediction, predict

I have a prediction model with several categorical and numerical variables. I am needing to forecast the mpg of a car given a list of all the main effects and their values. These main effects are cylinders, horsepower, weight, model year, displacement, and acceleration. I started with a model of all main effects and two way interactions. With backward selection, my model has dropped displacement and model year main effects. The model also dropped most interaction terms so there are no interaction terms with either displacement or model year. My main reason for this analysis is to perform predictions of new observations for mpg and I am given a list of values for all main effects, but my final model doesn't have some of the main effects. Is it okay if I make predictions of new observations with a model that has dropped some of the main effects even though the new observations rely on values from those dropped main effects?

I've tried creating another model using forward selection starting with the additive model so all main effects are represented within the prediction model, but the RMSE was absurdly large.

Comment: This seems like it is from the `mtcars` data, could you please edit the question to include a reproducible example?